# Parallel Writes Of Multiple DataFrames in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scenario , where I have to write multiple data frames into parquet format.
I have used this

```
df.write
      .format("parquet")
      .mode(<write-mode>)
      .option("compression", "gzip")
      .save(<file-path>)
```

Now , I have around 15 data frames that will be writing the data to parquet. 
I see at a time only one task is getting executed (so , only 1 data frame is getting written) . Also when I checked the number of active executors in the spark-ui , I see only 1 executor is being used[image]

My questions are :

- Can I use parallel writes to the parquet store for a single data
  frame  ?
- Can I do parallel writes of multiple data frames to
  parquet(instead of the write happening sequentially)?

Answer (score -1):

Certainly possible. https://georgheiler.com/2019/12/05/parallel-aggregation-of-dataframes/
Is a nice example I created recently.

The main thing is you need to issue actions / writes in parallel on the driver. Thus means you somehow manually need to manage threads and concurrency.

But equally important is to set sparks scheduler to fair mode. Otherwise it will submit in parallel and only work in parallel if additional slots are free. At least in your setting this doesn't seem to be like that. So only when setting it to fair, the scheduler will give every running action an equal share of slots.

You potentially could create multiple pools of resources.